# How to reformat a string that represents a big-endian into a MAC-Address format?

Tags: python, string, format, endianness

I have the following string parsing problem. Given an endian-like string output a string with a MAC-address format. Example:

Input: `'\x01\xfa'`

Output: `'01:fa'`

What I need is quite more complex but I am stuck performing this task. I appreciate any reference of a function that might help me doing such conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) with [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) and [`%` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```
>>> ':'.join('%02x' % ord(ch) for ch in '\x01\xfa')
'01:fa'
```

or with [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> ':'.join('{:02x}'.format(ord(ch)) for ch in '\x0a\xfa')
'0a:fa'
```

Comment: Thanks for the references and the solution as well.